# In Unity c# I can't get animations to transition using animation.SetInteger

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I'm trying to use Animator Controller component to transition from Idle animation to walking animation. I can't seem to get animator.SetInteger to work for me. I've tried it with and without the else statement. It works if I put it in the start funtion, but I need it to be tied to the walking input. Movement works fine and through the public float I can see the verticalInput changing when I press the key. I've also tried declaring Animator as public or private.

No compiler errors, but Unity throws this error when I hit play: `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Movement still works fine with play, just no animation unless I change the "Condition" parameter manually through the component.

I also tried `Debug.Log(animator.GetInteger("Condition"))`, but I guess that doesn't work like that.

Here's my script:

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 8;
    public float rotationalSpeed = 45;

    public float verticalInput;
    private float rotationalInput;

    private Animator animator;


    void Start()
    {
        Animator animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        //animator.SetInteger("Condition", 1);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        rotationalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * verticalInput * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * rotationalInput * rotationalSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        
        if (verticalInput != 0)
        {
            animator.SetInteger("Condition", 1);
        }
        else
        {
            animator.SetInteger("Condition", 0);
        }
        Debug.Log(animator.GetInteger("Condition"));
    }
}
```

Any Ideas to what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Your Animator is probably just not set in the Inspector and that's why it's not working. [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Is your animator component on the same game object that PlayerController component is?